# Trying to save raw data, which has been received from google drive, to server

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm making service, which allows to pick some of pdf files from user's Google Drive and then, script converts files to jpg. I'm stuck on dowloading files from Google Drive.

I'm getting files data like this:

```
function step3process()
{
    $("#content").empty();
    var pdf = checkedPdf[downloadedCnt];
    var i = downloadedCnt;
            gapi.client.request({
                'path': '/drive/v2/files/'+pdf,
                'method': 'GET',
                callback: function ( theResponseJS, theResponseTXT ) {
                    var myToken = gapi.auth.getToken();
                    var myXHR   = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    myXHR.open('GET', theResponseJS.downloadUrl, true );
                    myXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myToken.access_token );
                    myXHR.onreadystatechange = function( theProgressEvent ) {
                        if (myXHR.readyState == 4) {

                            if ( myXHR.status == 200 ) {


                                var rawcont = utf8_to_b64(myXHR.response);

                                $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        beforeSend: function(req) {
                                            req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
                                        },
                                        url: './savepdf.php',
                                        data: rawcont,
                                        dataType: "json"
                                    }

                                ).done(
                                    function (msg) {
                                        downloadedCnt++;
                                        console.log("Скачан файл " + msg.name + " Всего скачано " + downloadedCnt + " из " + checkedPdf.length);
                                        if (downloadedCnt < checkedPdf.length) step3process();
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    myXHR.send();


                }
            });


}
```

Server-side looks like:

```
if (isset($_POST))
{
    $pdfData = '';
    foreach($_POST as $p)
    {
        $pdfData .= $p;
    }
    $filteredData = $pdfData;

    $unencodedData = urldecode(base64_decode($filteredData));
    $fp = fopen($filepath, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose($fp);
    echo("{\"answer\": \"ok\", \"name\": \"{$filepath}\", \"length\": \"" . strlen($unencodedData) . "\" }");

}
```

After all, i get empty pdf like this: 
[upload result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtviC.png)

I've also noticed, that original pdf file and the downloaded one have some differences, here is the example:
[files in mcedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V62ds.png)

Solution to me will be if i could get pdf files with content. Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, i'd provided token to php:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: './downloadpdf.php',
                        data: "url="+ encodeURIComponent(downUrl) + "&name="+ encodeURIComponent(pdfNames[pdf]) +"&token=" + myToken.access_token,
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).done();
```

and downloaded file with php easily:

```
$url = urldecode($_POST['url']);
$name = urldecode($_POST['name']);
$token = $_POST['token'];


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
));

$filepath = "./pdf/{$name}";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL
$pdf = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents($filepath,$pdf);
```

still no idea, why could not save raw data. hope this helps some1